# How do i dequeue a cell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier eventCell  - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

heres the code

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {// this sets the title and subtitle to the Title and Location in the given EventPlan
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell ", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = eventsArray[indexPath.row].title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = eventsArray[indexPath.row].location

    return cell        
}


// here's my code for eventplan
class EventPlan : NSObject {
    var title:String
    var location:String

    init(tits: String, locs: String){
        self.title = tits
        self.location = locs
    }       
}

let event = EventPlan(tits: "Wise BDAY", locs: "UVA-Wise")
```

I know that im supposed to label the cell identifier as eventCell in my main story board but i still get the error. am  i not connecting it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally what you do is to set up prototype cells in your storyboard and set up the reuse identifier there in the storyboard. If you do that you don't need any code.

If you're defining your cell in a nibfile see the answers from Sandeep and Naveed, above. (Note that you'll need to edit the "nibName" parameter in both answers to use your nib name.

Comment: @KunjPatel if that solved your problem you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the cell with your table view. I usually do it in `viewDidLoad`.

```
// Swift 2
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "NIB_NAME", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "eventCell")

// Swift 3
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "NIB_NAME", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "eventCell")
```

Comment: See i did just that but im still getting the same message

Comment: @kunj-patel : Is your xib name eventCell.xib ??? In UINib(nibName: "eventCell", bundle: nil) you should specify xib name not reusable identifier string

Comment: override func viewDidLoad(){                                                                                     let nib = UINib(nibName: "eventCell", bundle: nil)
        self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "eventCell")
}

Comment: yes the name in main is eventCell, its the one that goes right under custom

Comment: Is your cell in its own `nib`, or is it a prototype cell in a `tableViewController`?

Comment: your right its a prototype cell in tableviewcontroller

Comment: if its a prototype cell in tableViewController u don't need to write register statement in ViewDidLoad. Make sure you have reusable identifier set up properly, clean and re run the code